# Bundle Install Rsruby Fails, But Gem Install Succeeds

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, bundler

I have ruby2.2, ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, and I want to install the rsruby gem.  Everything is set up, and all my other gems are set up, with "sudo bundle install."  But rsruby keeps crashing when I try to install it like that.  How do I debug it and make it work?

I have a script I run which runs this command

```
sudo bundle config build.rsruby "--with-R-include=/usr/share/R/include --with_cflags=\"-fPIC -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing\""
```

Then I run "sudo bundle install" and it crashes on RSRuby:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby2.2 -r ./siteconf20161028-31919-l2ks0n.rb extconf.rb
--with-R-include=/usr/share/R/include --with_cflags=\"-fPIC -g -O2
-fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wall
-fno-strict-aliasing\"
checking for main() in -lR... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.


from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:735:in `try_func'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:992:in `block in find_library'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:911:in `block in checking_for'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:910:in `checking_for'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:988:in `find_library'
from extconf.rb:15:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/rsruby-e72a8dc61617 for inspection.
Results logged to
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/rsruby-e72a8dc61617/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing rsruby (0.5.5), and Bundler cannot
continue.
```

But if I run

```
sudo gem install rsruby -- --with-R-dir=/usr/lib/R --with-R-include=/usr/share/R/include --with_cflags="-fPIC -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing"
```

Then it successfully installs

```
Fetching: rsruby-0.5.1.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions with: '--with-R-dir=/usr/lib/R --with-R-include=/usr/share/R/include --with_cflags=-fPIC -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed rsruby-0.5.1.1
Parsing documentation for rsruby-0.5.1.1
Installing ri documentation for rsruby-0.5.1.1
Done installing documentation for rsruby after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

SO, my question is, how do I debug this? And how do I get it working with bundle install? Thanks!

UPDATE, as matt pointed out in the comments, the version of the rsruby gem installed by the two commands was different.  if i change my Gemfile to specify bundle to install version "0.5.1.1" then "sudo bundle install" installs successfully. however, i need version "0.5.5". my Gemfile is currently set up like this, "gem 'rsruby', github: 'custora/rsruby'" and must get version 0.5.5. so why would 0.5.1.1 install correctly, but not 0.5.5?

UPDATE, mkmf.log

```
gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.1.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -I/usr/share/R/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   "-g conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -L/build/ruby2.1-3vrZnx/ruby2.1-2.1.9/debian/lib -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.1  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

Comment: Are those using two different versions of ruby?

Comment: yes matt, i just noticed that as well.  so to add more info to what is happening, if i change my Gemfile to specify bundle to install version "0.5.1.1" then it "sudo bundle Install" installs successfully.  however, i need version "0.5.5".  my Gemfile is currently set up like this, "gem 'rsruby', github: 'custora/rsruby'" and must get version 0.5.5.  so why would 0.5.1.1 install correctly, but not 0.5.5?

Comment: thanks for pointing this out matt, the post is updated with the new info, im still stuck on it and cannot get the version i need to install

Comment: Where did you get the source for rsruby 0.5.5? On github I see the final version was 0.5.1.1 and was released about five years ago.

Comment: this is a joint project i am working on with others.  the guy in charge set up the gemfile to say "gem 'rsruby', github: 'custora/rsruby'" and as far as i can see, those are the only commands telling the server which runs this project where to get rsruby, and the version of rsruby when i do bundle list on the server is, "rsruby (0.5.5 e72a8dc)".  does that answer your question? figuring out this problem is kind of new to me.

Comment: this is running properly on a server.  and it was running on my computer fine.  but a couple weeks ago i bought a new laptop and am stuck getting this set up.

Comment: Oh yeah I shouldn't have over thought this. Your problem is probably that you don't have R installed so ruby cannot build the extension. Also you seem to keep jumping between ruby versions for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so there were a few different things going on here.  I will document them all here in case someone else who needs to use rsruby comes across this.  First, as Matt pointed out, bundle install and gem install were trying to install two different versions of rsruby.  Second, I had to change this script which I ran to set the bundle configuration options, this script did NOT work.  To make this work, I replaced the `\"` with `'`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Does /usr/bin/gem link to /usr/bin/gem2.1 ?
# gem install bundler -v 1.6.0.rc2
sudo bundle config build.rsruby "--with-R-include=/usr/share/R/include --with-cflags=\"-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -fPIC\""
```

The above two steps made rsruby install.  But after that I kept getting segfault errors anyway.  The problem seems to have been either an old distro of ubuntu, or the fact that since it was an old distro of ubuntu, I had to use brightbox repo to get a more recent version of ruby.  In any case, after updating to a current distro of linux which had a current version of ruby, it worked.